# my sprite dont show in libgdx

Tags: libgdx, sprite

Hi i am new to libgdx and try to build a ludo game.right know i could draw the board but when i try to show dice or any peaces nothing happens I attach game code .
please read and help.

```
public void create() {
    float w = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float h = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(1, h / w);
    boardtexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/ludo-boardx2.png"));
    boardtexture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);
    boardsprite = new Sprite(boardtexture);
    boardsprite.setSize(1f,
            1f * boardsprite.getHeight() / boardsprite.getWidth());
    boardsprite.setOrigin(boardsprite.getWidth() / 2,
            boardsprite.getHeight() / 2);
    boardsprite.setPosition(-boardsprite.getWidth() / 2,
            -boardsprite.getHeight() / 2);
    Texture dice = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/dices.png"));
    dice.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear, TextureFilter.Linear);

    dtemp = new Sprite(dice);
    dtemp.setSize(1f, 1f * dtemp.getHeight() / dtemp.getWidth());
            dtemp.setPosition(0f, 0f);


    // System.out.println(w/2+" " +h/2);
    // System.out.println(dtemp.getWidth()+":"+dtemp.getHeight());
    // animatedDice.setPosition(new Vector2(0, 0));
    System.out.println(animatedDice.getX() + ":" + animatedDice.getY()
            + "\n" + w + ":" + h);

}
  public void render() {
  Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
  Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

  batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
  // camera.update();
  handleInput();
  batch.begin();
  boardsprite.draw(batch);
  dtemp.draw(batch);
  //animatedDice.draw(batch);
  batch.end();
  // animatedDice.update();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are drawing your die at a position of `(w/2, h/2)`, which is way out of range of your viewport. You set your viewport so the X coordinate of the right side of your screen is 0.5, but your sprite's left side is at `x=w/2`, where w is the number of pixels wide your window is.

Even if you had set your camera size to match the window (`(w, h)`), you would have an issue here because you'd be drawing your sprite so its left edge matched the right edge of the screen. By default, the origin of your die sprite will be its lower left corner.

If you aren't planning to zoom your scene in and out, it might be simpler to set your camera viewport to the size of the window by using `camera = new OrthographicCamera(w, h);` Then you'll know that your units are equivalent to pixels.

Comment: can you explain more about setting viewport in this state.I mean based of what calculations you say X coordinate of the right side of your screen is 0.5 . I need more explaination to understand .

Comment: The constructor `new OrthographicCamera(width, height)` defines the units of your game world. Whatever numbers you put in there set the scale of your units. The width is how many units wide your viewport is, so if you set it to `1` like you did, then a sprite with width of 1 will be exactly the same width of the screen. The screen is one unit wide, with the center at (0,0), so the right edge of the screen lines up with the X-coordinate 0.5.

Comment: I tryed to draw th dice in the (0,0) to be displayed in the center of the screen with no chance. can you tell me the right position of the dice to be drawn in the center of the screen

Comment: No dice, huh? :) Did you set the size of the dice sprite to be smaller than the camera viewport width? If the dice sprite is something like 50 units wide while the screen is only one unit wide, you're only going to see the bottom left pixel of it, which might be a transparent pixel.

Comment: I updateed my code based of our conversation with no chance can you take a look

Comment: I can't find any other issues that would prevent you from seeing the sprite. So the board is showing correctly? What if you comment out the line for drawing the board? Maybe you should take this to the libgdx forums. http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/

Comment: How can I set my sprite size to the correct size that can be showed? for example if my spprite is 50*50 and board is 800*480 for showing in the camera viewport (1, h / w) whats the correct sizes?

Comment: If you insist on using viewport  (1, h / w), then you should scale all sprites by the same amount. In your case it seems to be an amount of `w/800`. So each sprite should be scaled like: `sprite.setSize(sprite.getWidth()*w/800f, sprite.getHeight*w/800);`. But if you just use `new OrthographicCamera(w, h)` you won't need to scale any sprites at all. Also note that you are setting yourself up to be able to support only screens with a 15:9 ratio. That's another problem that can be solved with a Viewport strategy. I can't explain all that in comments. You can read through the libgdx docs on that.

Comment: thanks for your comments.I think I go for (w, h) in your opinion what is best resolution that fit every android device?(phone or tablet)

Comment: That's kind of long discussion. See here(http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=13044), but there is a relatively new Viewport class that can simplify this kind of stuff.